# How to prevent repeating the following .push() action?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm writing a fucntion that validates forms. I'm using the `every` method to make sure that all the conditions are being passed. If the field isn't valid, the falsy value is returned and its name is pushed to a `invalidFields` array. If everything goes well, the function returns `true`:

```
validateForm () {
  this.isValid = this.validatingFields.every(field => {
    const pattern = field.validation.pattern
    const match = field.validation.match
    if (match) {
      const matchRegex = this.convertToRegex(match)
      if (!matchRegex.test(field.value)) this.invalidFields.push(field.name)
      return matchRegex.test(field.value)
    }
    if (pattern) {
      if (pattern.test(field.value)) this.invalidFields.push(field.name)
      return pattern.test(field.value)
    }
    return true
  })
}
```

But as you can see I have to do `this.invalidFields.push(field.name)` in every if statement. Is there a way to avoid this repetition?

**EDIT:** The input looks like this:

```
    validatingFields: [{
      name: 'name',
      type: 'text',
      value: '',
      validation: {
        required: true
      }
    }, {
      name: 'company',
      type: 'text',
      value: '',
      validation: {
        // pattern: util.regex().email
        match: 'name'
        // minLength: 2,
        // maxLength: 4
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you just put both cases into one if statement with extra `OR`:

```
validateForm() {
    this.isValid = this.validatingFields.every(field => {
        const pattern = field.validation.pattern
        const match = field.validation.match
        if ((match && !this.convertToRegex(match).test(field.value)) || (pattern && pattern.test(field.value))) {
            this.invalidFields.push(field.name)
            return match ? this.convertToRegex(match).test(field.value)) : pattern.test(field.value)
        }
        return true
    })
}
```

But it's definitely less maintainable code. So I personally don't see a reason to do it.